# При мердже изменений с удалённого репозитория, забирается не весь актуальный код

Tags: git, repository, git-merge

Находясь на своей ветке,после успешно выполненной команды git Fetch, пытаюсь слить взятые изменения с
origin master  ветки со своей веткой..Вебшторм рапортует,что успешно забрано столько то файлов.. дальше стартую проект находясь на своей ветке..  проект падает(ctrl+shift+r делал),перехожу на origin master  стартую проект с него, всё работает..Получается, что у меня на моей ветке не самый свежий код.. как можно это исправить?Кроме как каждый раз плодить новые ветки с мастера

Comment: Проверьте коммиты по названиям, у вас локально есть последний с origin master? Причин локального падения проекта очень много, тем более, что в этой ветке есть и новый код - "гит не всё стянул" одна из последних, которые я стала бы рассматривать

Comment: Да есть,и что самое странное, когда я запускаю код на первом компьютере там всё работает.. Запускаю этот же код на ноутбуке(и там и там версии кода последние)-проект падает.

Comment: JS.Понимаете, но у 2хдругих человек почему-то таких проблем нету

Comment: Либо в коде есть отличия, либо код к примеру проверяет наличие какого то файла, которого на Вашей машине нет

Comment: @ZdraviSmisl то есть, из вашей ветки на других машинах проект работает без проблем? Похоже, проблема вообще не в гите. Добавьте бэктрейс вашей ошибки, чуть больше деталей, переименуйте вопрос и смените теги - так гораздо больше шансов решить проблему